# Amazon CloudWatch boto API plugin, not returning all metrics available through UI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Problem #1: I'm writing a monitoring script for Nagios to pull data from CloudWatch and alert at certain thresholds. I am using the boto plugin for python. When I query list_metrics it doesn't return all metrics available to me under the CloudWatch UI.

For example I'm trying to get the following metrics:

```
**metric_list = [ 'Metric:GetMisses',
                'Metric:CmdGet',
                'Metric:CPUUtilization',
                'Metric:CmdSet']**
```

The only problem is **CmdSet** doesn't get returned from list_metrics. Although If I login to the cluster and view that metric there is recorded data for it. The API does not return this metric, but it returns **CmdSet**.

conn.list_metrics() as read from boto's site should return a list of all recorded metrics.

```
 ***list_metrics(next_token=None, dimensions=None, metric_name=None, namespace=None)

    Returns a list of the valid metrics for which there is recorded data available.
    Parameters: 

        next_token (str) – A maximum of 500 metrics will be returned at one time. If more results are available, the ResultSet returned will contain a non-Null next_token attribute. Passing that token as a parameter to list_metrics will retrieve the next page of metrics.
        dimensions (dict) – A dictionary containing name/value pairs that will be used to filter the results. The key in the dictionary is the name of a Dimension. The value in the dictionary is either a scalar value of that Dimension name that you want to filter on or None if you want all metrics with that Dimension name. To be included in the result a metric must contain all specified dimensions, although the metric may contain additional dimensions beyond the requested metrics. The Dimension names, and values must be strings between 1 and 250 characters long. A maximum of 10 dimensions are allowed.
        metric_name (str) – The name of the Metric to filter against. If None, all Metric names will be returned.
        namespace (str) – A Metric namespace to filter against (e.g. AWS/EC2). If None, Metrics from all namespaces will be returned.***


import boto.ec2.cloudwatch
import datetime
import os
import subprocess

end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
start = end - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

conn = boto.ec2.cloudwatch.connect_to_region("us-east-1")

metrics = conn.list_metrics()

metric_list = [ 'Metric:GetMisses',
                'Metric:CmdGet',
                'Metric:CPUUtilization',
                'Metric:CmdSet']

for metric in metrics:
    print metric
    define_metric_name = str(metric)
    if 'Set' in define_metric_name:
        print metric

    if define_metric_name in metric_list:
        if 'Metric:CPUUtilization' == define_metric_name:
            datapoints = metric.query(start,end, 'Average', 'Percent')
            for data in datapoints:
                try:
                    print 'Average', data['Average'], 'Timestamp',data['Timestamp'], metric, metric.dimensions['CacheClusterId']
                except:
                    continue
        else:
            datapoints = metric.query(start,end, 'Sum', 'Count')
            for data in datapoints:
                try:
                    print 'Sum', data['Sum'], 'Timestamp',['Timestamp'], metric, metric.dimensions['CacheClusterId']
                except:
                    continue
    else:
        continue
```

if I print out the metric list CmdSet is not there.

Link to Boto's site

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/cloudwatch.html

Link to CloudWatch Documentation

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheMetrics.Memcached.html

Comment: This is quite a big question. You may get more effective help by splitting these up into separate ones.

Comment: @ne1410s thanks yea I might do that thanks for the tip.